# Open WiFi Settings by using openurl with param App-Prefs:root=WiFi do not work in iOS 11 any more

Tags: ios, wifi, ios11

If any other way to open WiFi Settings in iOS 11?
This function is very important to my app.
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: The prefs URLs are unsupported.  Officially, the only preference you can open is your own app's preferences.

Comment: I know，but many big companies's app are using this api to open system wifi page. So i just want to know if this api had been banned by Apple completely.

Comment: You can try logging a bug against the beta, but I believe Apple have clearly stated previously that the prefs urls are considered private

Comment: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65007